# Can we do [self release];?

Tags: ios, object, release

It works... it doesn't crash, and it appears to do what I need.

This could be a design flaw of my application but its the easiest way to do what I need. Basically a view is displayed and controls within the object itself determine when it is removed from the superview (at which point it needs to be released).

At this point its easiest to do `[self release]`, which appears to work.

However, I'm aware of object ownership, and I'm aware that instantiating an object which releases itself is not a good design of object ownership - ie the owner class (the one which instantiates the new object) should be the one which releases it. This would then, however, require me to write delegate methods calling back to the owner class, all just to release the object.

Thoughts please? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically a view is displayed and controls within the object itself determine when it is removed from the superview (at which point it needs to be released).

Usually, the superview has the retained reference to the child view, and when it gets removed, that reference is released. Why do you need to release it again?

If you do [self release] you are removing ownership of this object from some other piece of code (that holds a retained reference to it). If you do that, that other piece of code will still have a non-nil reference to a piece of garbage memory. It seems to me that this other piece of code should be notified of this situation (and then it might as well issue the release itself).

> Once added to the superview I can just release?

The [pattern you usually see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283324/is-it-better-to-autorelease-or-release-right-after) in code samples is

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame...];
[self addSubView:view];
[view release];
```

Comment: hmm, you make a good point. Once added to the superview I can just release?

Comment: That is how it is usually done. Problem is when you have some other object (a controller) that also needs to have a reference to the subview (that it also needs to retain). But even if you then [self release]'d, that controller would still need to be notified somehow, because it now has a reference to trash.

Comment: Yea, @Thilo is right, the case here is that he's not creating a UIView, he has a UIViewController with its view (which it retains!)

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you're doing, and you're your own class' client, you're fine.
About being a bad design: you're right. I'd suggest to notify the class that is instantiating the one you want to release that it's disappeared, so it can release it. You could use a protocol, or NSNotificationCenter.