# Yet another iOS memory management clarification about autorelease / release usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to autorelease or release right after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283324/is-it-better-to-autorelease-or-release-right-after)

(forward notice: please do not discuss this topic in terms of ARC)

we have an internal debate in our company, the topic is the usage of autorelease / early-release. Let me explain it.

Scenario 1:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
self.myRetainingProperty = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

Scenario 2:

```
self.myRetainingProperty = [NSArray array]; // or [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Basically both scenarios are perfectly okay, however I would be curious what's the communities' approach to using these scenarios ? I would prefer the "release as soon as possible" (scenario 1) - especially on iOS where memory could be precious, but on the other hand an autoreleased object (scenario 2) which lives until the next runloop cycle wouldn't put too much stress on the memory footprint.

So my question is which one do you prefer, or is there any Apple recommended way of doing this ?

And once again: please, let's disregard ARC for the moment :) ...

Thanks.

Comment: Can we also disregard that both examples are pointless since they create an immutable, empty array? ;)

Comment: a ton of questions - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=release+vs+autorelease

Answer (score 1):

As far as memory usage the same are equivalent. The only difference is the size of the Autorelease pool. As you are assigning them to a property the object won't be deallocated when you `release` it, as such the difference in memory difference will be that to store an entry in the autorelease pool. There is a little overhead in the autorelease pool, but in these type of cases it is usually negligible. You should do what feels natural and what makes the code easy to read / maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite often you use this for immutable object, however for NSMutableArray its a different thing.

```
NSMutableArray *myList = [[NSMutablearray alloc] init];
Someobject *myObject = [[Someobject alloc] init];
[myList addObject:myObject];
[myObject release];
[self setList:myList];
[myList release];
```

I often use it as above. On iPhone/iPad when you have limited amount of memory I think its a good habbit to cleanup unused memory as soon as possible. I only use autorelease when there is no other option available.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, it's just a question of memory management  :-)  and performance.

If you're allocating a single and simple object, an autorelease should be ok. I guess that 1 Ko of memory should not be criticial for your app.

But... If you allocate an object that takes a lot of memory, or allocate many many objects that takes some little memory, in a loop for example, you would be advised to release them as soon as possible. If not, you may have performance problem, and your app's `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method (and its consequences) will be called more often in the best case.

Everything depends on what kind of optimisation you want : Optimise the app... or optimise the developer :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you are performing the operation many times within the run loop then early release is preferable to prevent a large autorelease pool building up. Otherwise, it makes no difference and is down to personal preference.

I'm personally in the early release camp, if only to avoid too many nested square brackets.